# Populate a new column in a dataframe with a lookup from a double matrix

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df:

```
colour  shape
'red'   circle
'blue'  square
'blue'  circle
'green' sphere
```

And a double matrix m with named rows/columns

```
      circle square sphere  
red   1      4      7
blue  2      5      8
green 3      6      9
```

I'd like to add a new column to DF such that I obtain:

```
id  colour  shape
1   'red'   circle
5   'blue'  square
2   'blue'  circle
9   'green' sphere
```

I've tried doing this with the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
df$id <- m[df$colour,df$shape]
```

I've also tried apply(); and similar but with no luck. Can anyone tell me the right approach to doing this without using a loop?

Comment: Thanks all for help. Both @Tommy 's answer below, and DWin's answers below work great for this. I went with DWin's for my scenario as I had character vectors in my real data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I might win the shortest answer contest here as long as those are character vectors rather than factors which might be more expected unless you made specifid effort to avoid. It really only adds `cbind` to convert the two df "character" vectors to a two column matrix expected by the `[.matrix` function that you were very close to success in using. (And it also seems reasonably expressive.)

```
# Data construct
d <- data.frame(color=c('red','blue','blue','green'), 
shape=c('circle','square','circle','sphere'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 m <- matrix(1:9, 3,3, dimnames=list(c('red','blue','green'), c('circle','square','sphere')))
# Code:

 d$id <- with( d, m [ cbind(color, shape) ] )
 d
  color  shape id
1   red circle  1
2  blue square  5
3  blue circle  2
4 green sphere  9
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the levels in `d` have the same order as the rownames/colnames in m. I tried to explain that in my answer. Try it again with `m<-m[3:1,]` and see that it fails...

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't read carefully enough: given that `d` contains character vectors and not factors it actually works... My solution works in either case though ;-)

Comment: One could also use `m[ cbind(as.character(d$color), as.character(d$shape)]` which I think is both general and more clear.

Comment: ...which is what I suggested in my (earlier) answer ;-) - I only split it into two lines for clarity. However, this solution is a bit slower than mine that uses `match`...

Comment: @Tommy: I do see that your answer has similarities but I thought (incorrectly now that I checked it) that using a second `cbind` would silently coerce all its columns to a common class. I see now that `cbind.data.frame` doesn't do that. The help page says in two different places that `cbind.data.frame` will  silently covert character columns to factors. In this case it's not a problem , but I have been burned by `cbind.data.frame` behavior in the past and I avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

A rather simple (and fast!) alternative is to use a matrix to index into your matrix:

```
# Your data
d <- data.frame(color=c('red','blue','blue','green'), shape=c('circle','square','circle','sphere'))
m <- matrix(1:9, 3,3, dimnames=list(c('red','blue','green'), c('circle','square','sphere')))

# Create index matrix - each row is a row/col index
i <- cbind(match(d$color, rownames(m)), match(d$shape, colnames(m)))

# Now use it and add as the id column...
d2 <- cbind(id=m[i], d)

d2
#  id color  shape
#1  1   red circle
#2  5  blue square
#3  2  blue circle
#4  9 green sphere
```

The `match` function is used to find the corresponding numeric index for a particular string.

Note that in newer version of R (2.13 and newer I think), you can use character strings in the index matrix. Unfortunately, the color and shape columns are typically `factors`, and `cbind` doesn't like that (it uses the integer codes), so you need to coerce them with `as.character`:

```
i <- cbind(as.character(d$color), as.character(d$shape))
```

...I suspect that using `match` is more efficient though.

**EDIT** I measured and it seems to be about 20% faster to use `match`:

```
# Make 1 million rows
d <- d[sample.int(nrow(d), 1e6, TRUE), ]

system.time({
  i <- cbind(match(d$color, rownames(m)), match(d$shape, colnames(m)))
  d2 <- cbind(id=m[i], d)
}) # 0.46 secs


system.time({
  i <- cbind(as.character(d$color), as.character(d$shape))
  d2 <- cbind(id=m[i], d)
}) # 0.55 secs
```

Comment: As long as @Tommy brings it up, the solution converting m to a vector takes 0.14 seconds compared to 0.50 seconds for the first example above on my machine ;)

Comment: I've marked @DWin 's answer are correct as that's the one I used (I prefer the simplicity and don't have time constraints), but this answer works great too and I really appreciate the effort that went into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another answer Using the **reshape2** and **plyr** (optional just for join) packages.

```
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)

Df <- data.frame(colour = c("red", "blue", "blue", "green"), 
                  shape = c("circle", "square", "circle", "sphere"))

Mat <- matrix(1:9, dimnames = list(c("red", "blue", "green"),
                                   c("circle", "square", "sphere")), 
                    nrow = 3)

Df2 <- melt.array(Mat, varnames = c("colour", "shape"))

join(Df, Df2)
result <- join(Df, Df2)

join(Df, Df2)
Joining by: colour, shape
  colour  shape value
1    red circle     1
2   blue square     5
3   blue circle     2
4  green sphere     9
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

`merge()` is your friend here. To use it, we need an appropriate data frame to merge with containing the stacked version of your ID matrix. I create that as `newdf` with the code below:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
colnames(df) <- c("circle","square","sphere")
rownames(df) <- c("red","blue","green")

newdf <- cbind.data.frame(ID = unlist(df), 
                          expand.grid(colour = rownames(df), 
                                      shape = colnames(df)))
```

Which results in:

```
> newdf
        ID colour  shape
circle1  1    red circle
circle2  2   blue circle
circle3  3  green circle
square1  4    red square
square2  5   blue square
square3  6  green square
sphere1  7    red sphere
sphere2  8   blue sphere
sphere3  9  green sphere
```

Then with your original data in object `df2`, defined using

```
df2 <- data.frame(colour = c("red","blue","blue","green"),
                  shape = c("circle","square","circle","sphere"))
```

use `merge()`

```
> merge(newdf, df2, sort = FALSE)
  colour  shape ID
1    red circle  1
2   blue circle  2
3   blue square  5
4  green sphere  9
```

You can store that and rearrange the columns if you need that:

```
> res <- merge(newdf, df2, sort = FALSE)
> res <- res[,c(3,1,2)]
> res
  ID colour  shape
1  1    red circle
2  2   blue circle
3  5   blue square
4  9  green sphere
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert the matrix m to a vector and then match the ID to the colour and shape values:

```
df<-data.frame(colour=c("red","blue","blue","green"),
  shape=c("circle","square","circle","sphere"))


m<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3,dimnames=list(c("red","blue","green"),
  c("circle","square","sphere")))


mVec<-as.vector(m)
```

The next step matches the colour in df to the appropriate dimname in the m matrix, then adds an integer corresponding to the shape. The result in the index of the m vector with the corresponding ID.

```
df$ID<-mVec[match(df$colour, dimnames(m)[[1]]) + (dim(m)[1]*
  (match(df$shape, dimnames(m)[[2]]) - 1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#recreating your data
dat <- read.table(text="colour  shape
'red'   circle
'blue'  square
'blue'  circle
'green' sphere", header=TRUE)

d2 <- matrix(c(1:9), ncol=3, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
dimnames(d2) <-list(c('circle', 'square', 'sphere'),
c("red", "blue", "green"))
d2<-as.table(d2)

#make a list of matching to the row and column names of the look up matrix
LIST <- list(match(dat[, 2], rownames(d2)), match(dat[, 1], colnames(d2)))
#use sapply to index the lookup matrix using the row and col values from LIST 
id <- sapply(seq_along(LIST[[1]]), function(i) d2[LIST[[1]][i], LIST[[2]][i]])
#put it all back together
data.frame(id=id, dat)
```